# Create a spring boot application with multiple child contexts

Tags: spring, spring-boot, applicationcontext, hierarchical

I'm trying to create an application using spring boot with an hierarchical application context.
My current main method looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(TestApplication.class)
            .child(AuditServiceConfiguration.class).web(true)
            .child(TaskServiceConfiguration.class).web(true)
            .run(args);
}
```

and the two children configurations are annotated with:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
```

The idea is to have a parent context containing all common beans and each child context to run its own MVC while being isolated from its siblings.

Unfortunately when I run the above, only the last child context is initialised and started.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Alessandro

Comment: @[Alessandro Di Bella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5243501/alessandro-di-bella): Have you solved your problem?
How about [ESala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2597143/esala)'s answer?

Answer (score 22):

The `child(...)` method creates and **returns** another `SpringApplicationBuilder`, so when you call that second `child(...)` method, you are not instantiating a brother for the child, you are making a child on the first child, which makes the parent become a *grandpa*.

Jokes aside, have a look at the [sibling(...)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.html#sibling-java.lang.Object...-) method which allows to create another context with the same parent.

You can also check out the [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.java#L251) to see exactly what is going on.